# How to add a total in a table of dynamically created tr tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I'm creating a order like table in which each item is added to the table dynamically. Once an item (a tr element with a few tds) is added to the table there is a `$('table').on('change', 'td.qty-class', function(){}` to update the value for that particular element (td with price).

How can I add the total value for each (tr even after being updated) to a total using jQuery?

Here's what I've written:

```
// When click on button, add the product
$productBTN.click(function() {

        var prod = {};

        prod.name = $(this).children('.productName').text(),
        prod.price = parseInt($(this).children('.productPrice').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '')),
        prod.unitPrice = parseInt($(this).children('.productPrice').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '')),
        prod.id = Utils.fnGenerateUUID();

        $('table.order-list tbody').append(
            '<tr class="product_class ' + prod.name + '" id="' + prod.id + '">' +
                '<td>' +
                '<select class="form-control product-qty input-sm">' +
                '<option>1</option>' +
                '<option>2</option>' +
                '<option>3</option>' +
                '<option>4</option>' +
                '<option>5</option>' +
                '<option>6</option>' +
                '<option>7</option>' +
                '<option>8</option>' +
                '<option>9</option>' +
                '</select>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></td>' +
                '<td>' + prod.name + '</td>' +
                '<td><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Note</button></td>' +
                '<td class="unit-price hidden">£ ' + prod.price + '</td>' +
                '<td class="prd-price">£ ' + prod.price + '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
        );

        // Add the product to a order object
        order.products[prod.id] = prod;

        // Change the price on the table when quantity changes
        $('table.order-list').on('change', '.product-qty', function() {

            var $prrd = $(this).parents('.product_class');
            $prrd.id = $(this).parents('.product_class').attr('id');
            $prrd.price = $(this).parents('.product_class').find('.prd-price').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
            $prrd.unitPrice = $(this).parents('.product_class').find('.unit-price').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
            $prrd.qty = $(this).val();

            $prrd.find('.prd-price').html('£ ' + $prrd.qty * $prrd.unitPrice);

            order.products[$prrd.id].price = $prrd.qty * $prrd.unitPrice;

        });

    });
```

But now I'm not sure on how to proceed in order get the total: I thought about looping through each tr and get the value of price td, but as each tr is being created dynamically that hasn't worked. I've tried setup a new $('table').on('change', function(){}) but that hasn't worked. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the page never refreshes you can use a Javascript global variable and up that one every time you need it to be upped. The global can be used throughout your entire Javascript file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your variable on the starting of your js:

```
window.totalValue = 0;
```

Add this on your change function:

```
window.totalValue = window.totalValue + (parseFloat($prrd.qty) * parseFloat($prrd.unitPrice));
```

Becoming that function:

```
    $('table.order-list').on('change', '.product-qty', function() {

        var $prrd = $(this).parents('.product_class');
        $prrd.id = $(this).parents('.product_class').attr('id');
        $prrd.price = $(this).parents('.product_class').find('.prd-price').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        $prrd.unitPrice = $(this).parents('.product_class').find('.unit-price').text().replace( /^\D+/g, '');
        $prrd.qty = $(this).val();

        window.totalValue = window.totalValue + (parseFloat($prrd.qty) * parseFloat($prrd.unitPrice));

        $prrd.find('.prd-price').html('£ ' + $prrd.qty * $prrd.unitPrice);

        order.products[$prrd.id].price = $prrd.qty * $prrd.unitPrice;

    });
```